# Delphi XE5 Android Dev "unable to open database file"

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe5

I followed this tutorial step by step [Mobile Tutorial: Using SQLite (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Using_SQLite_%28iOS_and_Android%29) but when I deploy my application on my android device and attempt to add an entry, I get the following error **"unable to open database file"**

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
procedure TForm1.rappadAfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
      rappad.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, content TEXT NOT NULL);');
end;

procedure TForm1.rappadBeforeDisconnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  rappad.Params.Values['ColumnMetadataSupported'] := 'False';
  rappad.Params.Values['Database'] :=
      TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'rappad.s3db');
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Does anyone know why is this actually happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have in your `rappadBeforeDisconnect` needs to be in **BeforeConnect** instead. There's no point in telling the connection where the database is located before you *disconnect*.

```
procedure TForm1.rappadBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  rappad.Params.Values['ColumnMetadataSupported'] := 'False';
  rappad.Params.Values['Database'] :=
      TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'rappad.s3db');
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that then then actually! It was because, in the object inspector, i accidentally clicked the BeforeDisconnect procedure instead of BeforeConnect. DUR! Silly me... Been stuck and confused for ages on that accident. Thank you! :)